# Is it possible to load a new web-page (on button click) if a conditional is true, otherwise do something on the same web page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web-applications

The structure of a part of my web page is like this:

[image]

The left `div` contains a reading passage (a simple paragraph) and the right `div` contains an MCQ based on the reading passage. The first problem I am facing is that the question object stored in the database contains the reading passage as well as the question's text. *So I am going to have to slice/sub-string the whole string in the question object to separate the question text from the reading passage.*

**The next challenge is that from the same reading passage, there can be more than one questions.**

*What is required is that the passage and the first question should display, then on the click of the `submit` button, the next question from the same reading passage should display in the right `div` (without loading a new webpage), while the left `div` and reading passage should remain there... this continues until we receive a question object which contains a different reading passage.*

I need to find a work around this: This is what I have thought. I need suggestions on this:

1. **Receive the question object on the click of the submit button.**
2. **Sub-string the question string to get the reading passage.**
3. **Compare this reading passage with the already displayed reading
   passage. If they are same, use JavaScript and display the next
   question in the right div on the same web page.**
4. **If they are different, load a new web-page with the new reading
   passage in the left div and its question in the right div.**

Mostly the last bit is confusing for me and I need to know *if I am on the right path.* **Please tell me if it is possible (especially the last bit, that is display a new web page only if the two strings being compared are not equal, on the click of the button)?**

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Why would it not be?

Comment: It's definitely possible - just use Ajax when you hit submit to pull the data from the database. It's just a matter of restructuring your fields so that you can accurately retrieve the next question, since they are currently combined with the passages, or calculating which portion of text to extract with methods like substring. You can use Ajax to replace any of the elements on the page, so you won't even need to leave the page.

Comment: if  you know php and javascript /jquery you can use `load` http://api.jquery.com/load/ and or `ajax` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ both jquery function

Comment: @RDrazard Firstly, thank you. The backend is in PHP and the client side in JS and HTML, I don't know AJAX yet, I'll try to learn if it does not work out with out with PHP and JQuery.

Comment: @inye Thank you very much. I hope it works out with `load`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Ajax call on click of button. Server side compare both strings and return some response. On ajax success check the response and take decision what to do whether reload page or not. And reload page using Javascript.

I think you understand the flow.

Comment: I am not sound with AJAX yet, the server side backend is in PHP and front end in HTML and JS. So I think using the JQuery suggestion of inye's comment is better option. But I understand the flow. So thank you very much.4

Comment: @Zarah Please use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), jQuery is just a slower, messier version of what [vanilla](http://vanilla-js.com) (plain) javascript already has.